Mongo DB Sharing Schema Files Across Servers
So I want to configure a set up where I have 2 node servers. Server 1 (Asset Server) is for shared assets and storing configs. Server 2 (API Server) will be more dedicated for api routes but will be dependent on Server 1's assets.
So, the Asset server can initializs databases and house all schemas for the different database connections I want to establish (i.e. database/entity1/User.js, database/entity2/User.js ....).
Now in the API Server I should expect that a database has been initialized and ready to be used, all I would want to do is retrieve those same schema files so I do not have to define and maintain in two different places, and make the connection with createConnection() and pass in url and schemas.
Once a connection is made, I want to store it in an object, so that when the front-end provides a "special identifier" in the request the api server can identify which database to connect to.
So my questions are,
**Am I able to serve and reuse the schema files from the asset server and use them in the api server?
Is this set up unnecessary complex or could there be a better approach? **
Ideally, the purpose of this set up so that I can share 1 back-end system across different online business entities, since most api routes will be the same. The only difference would be the database flow.
I have tried mounted the schema assets to the public folder to server them that way, but I wanted to maybe server them through a protected route. But I am also wanting to know if this set up makes sense or if there could be a much better way to set this up. Thank you in advance.
